# org.springframework.jndi.JndiLookupFailureException: JndiObjectTargetSource failed to obtain new target object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jboss, jndi, jboss-portal

I'm trying to deploy my application files app-ear-1.0.ear and mytest-portlet-1.0.war on jboss-portal-2.7.2, and after deploy (by copying app-ear-1.0.ear and mytest-portlet-1.0.war to jboss-portal-2.7.2/server/default/deploy) and opening the page with the portlet it is giving me the following error:

ERROR:

```
Cause: javax.portlet.PortletException: Request processing failed
Message: Request processing failed
StackTrace: 
javax.portlet.PortletException: Request processing failed
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.processRequest(FrameworkPortlet.java:544)
...
org.springframework.jndi.JndiLookupFailureException: JndiObjectTargetSource failed to obtain new target object; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: localhost:1099 and discovery failed with error: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out] [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]]]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectTargetSource.getTarget(JndiObjectTargetSource.java:139)
..
javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: localhost:1099 and discovery failed with error: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out] [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]]]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1562)
...
javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:274)
...
javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:248)
...
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
...
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

My web.xml (mytest-portlet/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
...

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="myTestService" jndi-name="app-ear-1.0/ejb/APPMyTest/remote"
                     proxy-interface="app.ejb.facade.portlet.mytest.IAPPMyTestService" lookup-on-startup="false">
        <jee:environment>
            java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
            java.naming.provider.url=jnp://localhost:1099
            java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
        </jee:environment>
    </jee:jndi-lookup>
</beans>
```

But on Windows 7 if do deployment from IntelliJ IDEA then all ok. What must to do on Mac OS X to make successful manual deployment by coping files on jboss-portal-2.7.2?